# Can a value from Groovy map be self referenced for interpolation purposes?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I want to know if we can interpolate a value within a Groovy map using it's other Key-Value entries. For example,

```
def ten = 10

def example = [
     a: "apple",
     b: "${ten} bats",
     c: "${example.b}" //or something like self.b
]
```

If so, please let me know how to get this done?

Comment: Guess: no you can't.  It's a literal and it evaluates the whole thing at once.

Comment: Not that I know of (not in a nice way anyway).  Maybe you could put this into config and use configslurper? I believe that allows elements to reference each other

Comment: @cfrick I got around this in Python using a self referencing class. But was wondering if there is a way for Groovy as well. Thanks for the reply man!

Comment: @tim_yates Awesome! I'll look into that configsluper. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 4):

As stated already in the comments, the literal for maps most likely does not allow that.  But you can come very close to your code there with `tap` (or `with` if you are <2.5)), which allows to lookup things inside the map (basically this is the self reference you where looking for)

E.g.

```
def ten = "ten"

def map = [:].tap{
    a = "apple"
    b = "${ten} ${a}s"
}

assert map == [a:"apple", b:"ten apples"]
```

Comment: That's awesome @cfrick. Appreciate it!